# Add Scroll Bar To Javascript Widget

Tags: javascript, css

I'm sorry, I know this is an easy one.  I have a javascript widget that I simply want to embed into my site adding a scroll bar to it.  Not sure if I can do this with CSS or if I can do this within the script.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<script src="//dashboard.time.ly/js/embed.js" data-src="https://events.time.ly/xkj6wcz" data-max-height="900" id="timely_script" class="timely-script"></script>
```

Comment: You need to show what you have attempted so far.  Just showing the link to the widget is asking people to write your code for you, which will not go over well.  Also ... please phrase your question as a question, not a request for generic assistance

Comment: What does _"adding a scroll bar to it"_ even mean? Like `overflow: scroll` for example?

Comment: @Tibrogargan my condolences, however, I'm not even sure where I should direction I should attempt.  This is the extent of the code I am embedding so, to ask a direct question: How can I add a scroll bar to the existing javascript widget I have here?  If someone can't point me in the right direction, I can do the research.  Again, my apologies for being a "newbie".  Just trying to learn.

Comment: @AngelPolitis I am trying to enable the content of the widget to scroll as opposed to being fixed.  My test page is located here: https://www.realtimehockey.net/testing.html "overflow: scroll" may be exactly what I'm looking for, however, I'm not sure where to add it.  Thanks.

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48273245/6313073) @Del6609.

Comment: @AngelPolitis thanks so much for your assistance.  Still haven't got it yet but, you definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome @Del6609. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `max-height: 900px;` from `.timely-frame` *(the `iframe`)* and add this to its parent:

```css
div {
   max-height: 900px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
#parent {
  max-height: 200px; /* To fit in the snippet. */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div id="parent">
  <iframe style="height: 1383px;" id="timely_0.06620993130795116f" name="timely_0.06620993130795116f" src="https://events.time.ly/xkj6wcz?id=timely_0.06620993130795116" seamless="" scrolling="no" class="timely-frame" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

---

**Note:** Be sure to give the parent a unique identifier, like I did in the snippet, otherwise all `div` elements will be styled that way.